# Irrationality of square roots of non-perfect squares using infinte descent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

To improve my understanding of infinte descent, I attempted to prove, using it, that any non-perfect square has an irrational square root.

> For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $n$ has no integer square root, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.
>
> *Proof.* Suppose not. Let $\sqrt{n} = \frac{a}{b}$. Since $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer, there exists $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $t<\sqrt{n}<t+1$. Thus,
> $$bt<a<b(t+1)$$
> $$0<a-bt<b.$$
> Now observe that
> $$n(a-tb)^2 = n\cdot a^2-n\cdot 2atb+n\cdot t^2b^2=n^2b^2 -2tnab+t^2a^2 = (nb-at)^2$$
> $$\sqrt{n} = \frac{nb-at}{a-tb}.$$
> We have above shown that $a-tb < b$, this implies we can descend through infinitely many smaller positive denominators, but that is impossible as a decreasing sequence of positive integers must always terminate.$\quad\square$

Is my proof correct ? Also, if $n=s^2$, the proof breaks because the inequality is not strict, right ?

Comment: We treasure mathematics for its precision. So I suggest that your title is too imprecise. It’s not the non-perfect squares that are irrational, but their square roots.

Comment: I edited the title. I hope this is not too precise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems correct, but with
$$
\sqrt{n}=\frac{|nb-at|}{a-tb}
$$
unless you prove that $nb>at$, which is however unneeded.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind next time.